# unable to get data from $_POST after getting it from javascript

Tags: php

I am sending data to php from javascript in this format :

```
var str = $('#description').summernote('code');
    var formData =  $('#form').serialize();
    var formData2=formData+'&data='+encodeURIComponent(str);

           $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'test.php',
                            data: formData2,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {

                            }
                        });
```

But, I'm unable to get the data in php.
I'm using :

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
```

to get title but it says that the index is not found and this it is an array and not a string . HOw can I get '**title**' data along with many other values?

But ,

```
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, var_export($_POST, true));
fclose($myfile);
```

gives me this :

```
array (
  'title' => 'test title',
  'from_datetime' => '',
 'sno' => ''22,
)
```

raw format from javascript console:

```
title=test%20title&from_datetime=&description=br%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E-----
```

form:

```
 <div id="form_div" >
            <form id="form"  method="post" action="javascript:submit_data();" >


                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input name="title" id="title" placeholder="title" type="text" class="form-control" >

                    </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input name="desc" id="desc" placeholder="desc" type="text" class="form-control" >

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Its not clear that you really  have a parameter named "title"

Comment: Try to var_dump($_POST) and see what it contains.

Comment: my guess is an error in how you're forming the string `formData`. But since you don't show that part, can't say what that is.

Comment: do you have a field, in the form, called `title`?

Comment: yes. I've update the code please check

Comment: everything is fine from javascript part. But I'm getting data as an array in php and $title=$_POST['title'] is not capturing that value

Comment: I've added more code. PLease check

Comment: can you add the form to the question

Comment: You need to view the request in the console network tab of your browser to view the raw body of the request. Make sure it is properly formatted. And you can also do a print_r of $_POST to view what is being sent over.

Comment: updated code. Also, submit_data() will call the above code!

Comment: Btw, I'm not getting any error nor am I getting any value in $title . But the var_export shows all key,values in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you do not send the appropriate data through ajax. Try to serialize all the data from your form

```
var dataSerialized = $('#form').serialize();

$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'test.php',
     data: dataSerialized,
     cache: false,
     success: function (data) {
         console.log('success');
     }
});
```

Then do a `var_dump($_POST);` in your `test.php` file to see if you receive the `title` field.
More about [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

The $_POST by definition passes [an associative array of variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), so the following formatting is normal.

```
array (
  'title' => 'test title',
  'from_datetime' => '',
  'sno' => ''22
)
```

What is not normal is that you do not have the same fields in the array as compared to the html code you show.

Comment: My answer was based on the initial post but the SO modified his question. Should I delete this outdated answer ?

Comment: Hey, How is the data different? I'm getting an array which has title and sending a parameter by name title as shown above. But $_POST['title'] is not capturing the value. Why?

Comment: From you raw javascript you got fields like 'title', 'datetime', 'description'. What is not the same as the fields that should be sent through the Form, that are 'title', 'desc'.

Comment: It seems you managed to find out. Explain what went wrong to help others understand. Thanks